# What’s the difference between ‘sich bekannt machen’ and ‘kennen lernen’?

Tags: meaning, difference, word-choice, phrase

Are the two phrases *sich bekannt machen* and *kennenlernen* different or can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Kennenlernen** (*kennen lernen* is also allowed since the 1996 spelling reform) roughly translates as *get to know*.

> Morgen werden Sie etwas Neues kennenlernen.

*Tomorrow you will get to know something new.*

While **sich bekanntmachen** (or *sich bekannt machen*) roughly translates as *to become acquainted*.

> Morgen werden Sie sich mit etwas Neuem bekanntmachen müssen.

*Tomorrow you have to become acquainted to something new.*

It can also be used without an object. That usually means a shakehands between two or more persons.

> Sie machten sich (miteinander) bekannt.

*They became acquainted to each other.*

The difference between the two is the intensity. To become acquainted with someone or something, just nodding "been there, seen that" isn't enough.